# Executing scenario even if one of the step is failed

Tags: specflow

Following is just normal example, If Test failed at Step
Then I see Level2 MenuLinks
It skip all next steps.
I would like to know if there is any option to keep executing other steps?

Thank you

```
Feature: Menu
    In order to check MenuLinks

Scenario Outline: Open a Page
    Given I have open the Page
    Given I see MenuLinks
    When I click on Level1 in MenuLinks
    Then I see Level2 MenuLinks
    And I go back to pagetemplate
    Given I see Level2 in MenuLinks
    When I click on Level2
    Then I see Level3 MenuLinks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Doing this will make it harder to see that the *Then* step has failed. If this is not actually important, why are you checking it?
But this one way to approach this, using a try catch:

In your step **Then I see Level2 MenuLinks**

```
[Then(@"I see Level2 MenuLinks")]
public void ISeeLevel2MenuLinks()
{
  try 
  {
         Execute your test here
  }
  catch
  {
         NotifyMeOnFailure();
         //A method that will notify you that the step failed. 
         //Because in specflow it will show as succesfully passed 
  }

}
```

Furthermore I would advise against the approach you have in your post. It would be better to create two different scenarios.

```
Scenario: Check for level2 menu links
  Given I have open the Page
  And I see MenuLinks
  When I click on Level1 in MenuLinks
  Then I see Level2 MenuLinks

Scenario: Check for level3 menu links
  Given I have open the Page
  When I click on Level1
  And I click on Level2
  Then I see Level3 MenuLinks
```

This way it is much easier to quickly detect where something went wrong.

Comment: Yes, please use multiple scenarios for it. It's like when you write unit tests. You only want to test for one thing!

Comment: Thank you for quick response, I will try to find a better way to have one thing to test in one scenario.