# How to skip a failed STEP on a TEST with Serenity-Cucumber

Tags: java, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

I use a Maven project with Java, Selenium WebDriver, JUnit, and Serenity with Screenplay.

I have a login with a pop-up that only appears sometimes, how can I add a validation STEP for the pop-up without failing the whole TEST if the pop-up doesn't appear?

Comment: use a try catch statement. put your step in your try block and the rest in the catch block and anything else that needs to run no matter what can be in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the test, in try-catch waiting for the popup. If it will appear - make needed actions, then go to next step, if don't appear - then just go to the next steps.
Here is almost same question with good answer: [Executing scenario even if one of the step is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690054/executing-scenario-even-if-one-of-the-step-is-failed)